How to keep this Inverse Kinematics setup from rotating out of plane?
How can I lock this IK setup to only allow rotated in the perpendicular plane (in the view it's the XZ plane)? Ideally this is supposed to be a piece of flat sheet metal on a floor with an IK rig to unfold and fold it from 0 degrees (flat) and be limited to a 90 degree angle. If there are any suggestions for simplifying the setup, that would be much appreciated because I will need to put in this IK rig (or similar rig) in about 15 other places. Thanks for any help on this.
For reference the IK bone is the bend.005-IK circled in red.




Does the plane need to be based on absolute coordinates, or can it be relative to the bone in question?

Hi @TheLabCat, relative to the bone. I’ll be needing to use this type of rig where the the flat peace might not always be flat against the global planes.

why can't you just use the lock buttons in the bones transform panel?
